# Род в дробном числительном

Tags: согласование, числительные, род

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно склонять дробное числительное:

*Колесная база автомобиля составляет **два** целых семь десятых метра.*
Или *две*?

Comment: Вопрос по существу очень КОНКРЕТНЫЙ: нужно указать правильную запись предложения. Также можно добавить сокращенную запись. Но зачем писать так много в основной части ответа? Конечно, все интересно, но сначала надо дать КОРОТКИЙ ОТВЕТ, а все остальное можно оформить как дополнение. ИНФОРМАТИВНЫЙ СТИЛЬ, сейчас он весьма востребован.С одной стороны, это стремление предоставить читателю максимум полезной ИНФОРМАЦИИ в сжатом виде. с другой — желание привлечь к себе больше читателей (коммерческая цель). Почему бы нам не работать в таком стиле: сначала ВЫВОД, а потом пояснение, а не наоборот.

Answer (score 2):

[Смешанные числительные](http://school-collection.edu.ru/dlrstore-wrapper/339d9c16-87f2-4aac-adb9-3f5120ff277c/g2014.htm#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8,(%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85).) — дробные числительные, в состав которых одновременно входят целые и дробные числительные (*пять **и** две сотых*) или в состав которых входит прилагательное “целый” (*пять целых две сотых*).

• Если прилагательное "целый" отсутствует, то между частями числительного (полной и дробной) появляется союз "и", а согласование полной части происходит **с родом** существительного:

м. р. — ***два** и семь десятых* (**метра**, килограмма, рубля, ампера, часа, гектара, литра, ребенка (в статистике));
ж. р. — ***две** и семь десятых* (**минуты**, калории, тонны, гривны, рупии, канделы).

Обычно такая запись используется тогда, когда из разговора или сообщения, в том числе и профессионального, всем понятно, о какой именно единице измерения идет речь.
Иногда даже "десятые" опускаются. Например, при измерении температуры тела ни сам человек, ни медик не скажет, что температура равна *тридцати шести целым шести десятым градуса*. "Тридцать шесть и шесть десятых" или "тридцать шесть и шесть" — вот как он скажет.

*Настя привычно разделила в уме новую цену на старую. Получилось ровно **два и семь десятых*** (А. Маринина. Стечение обстоятельств).
*Мой НП будет на высоте плюс **сто тридцать два и семь*** (Г. Бакланов. Навеки девятнадцатилетние).

• Если же "целый" присутствует, то согласование идет только по женскому роду:

***две** целых* [доли метра, части метра] *семь десятых метра.*
Сравните: ***одна** целая семь десятых метра* (не один целый!), ***две** целых **две** десятых метра* (не два десятых!).

[Дробные числительные](https://foxford.ru/wiki/russkiy-yazyk/drobnye-chislitelnye)

Comment: Здесь обсуждался вопрос о стилистке варианта "два и семь десятых метра", вот это интересно.  Вы указываете ссылки на источники информации, но насколько они авторитетны? Откуда эти ресурсы берут свои сведения? Хотелось бы увидеть ссылку на Грамматику-80 или что-нибудь подобное. Мне все-таки думается, что это разговорная форма (с пометкой "допускается").  Структура записи недостаточно строгая. Но Грамота.ру (вроде бы) не считает вариант разговорным. Но они тоже ничего не доказывают, как обычно.

Answer (score 1):

Так как педивикию писали буратины, пришлось гуглить:

[***База* автомобиля**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/66632/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0#:%7E:text=%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%20(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD)%2C,%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%81%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC) или ***база** колесных транспортных средств*, - а не *колесная база автомобиля*. Ну или "колёсная база", без "автомобиля", потому что **whellbase**. Но колесная база *автомобиля* уже тавтология.

[Колесная база](https://studopedia.info/1-21870.html#:%7E:text=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-,%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B,-%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0) составляет две целых семь десятых метра / или / 2, 7 метра.

И, "подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно *склонить*": склон**и**ть - глагол действия, а склон**я**ть - понятие, так как инфинитив. Это два разных слова.

*Склонить* его на свою сторону / *склонять* по падежам - от *склонение по падежам*.

"Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно *склон**я**ть* по падежам".

Либо

"Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно **просклонять** слово".

Из просклон**я**ть у вас никак не получится сделать просклон*и*ть.

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: @user190920 причем тут это? В ответе ни разу нет склон**и**ть, но склоняется, склонять. просто ответах не про слово склонять/склонить, а про результат склонения, вот все отвечают только на этот вопрос. Грамота отвечает на конкретный вопрос, и не придирается к остальной грамотности. Но так и быть, я добавлю еще просклонять, от него точно не образуешь слово просклонить.

Comment: То есть вы думаете, что грамота тупо не стала исправлять ошибки безграмотных вопрошающих (менять склонить на склонять/просклонять), а вы вот один потрудились исправить нашего автора, спасибо.

Comment: @user190920 именно так, думаю, грамота - тупо. Ну я исправил не "его ошибки", а то что увидел, прочитав. У меня не срослось. Можем оформить в отдельный вопрос и обсудить.

Comment: Грамота - тупо, именно поэтому они помешаны на вопросах оформления, там бы не стали отвечать только по сути, а обязательно бы исправили оформление. Думаю, нужен отдельный вопрос, и лучше если вы его сформулируете, потому что я ну вообще не вижу там ошибки. И сразу забудьте о слове "просклонить" оно к проблеме не относится

Comment: @user190920 почему не относится, когда просклонять - это выполнить склонение по родам. Просклонять = склонять по родам. А почему нет просклонить, если есть склонить по родам?

Comment: @user190920  Много раз замечал, что грамота далеко не всегда исправляет попутные ошибки, а отвечает только на поставленный вопрос. Это я вообще пишу, а не к вопросу про "склонить".

Comment: Я оформил вопрос. склонить и склонять - это хотя и разные глаголы, но с точностью до вида это один и тот же глагол. А вот просклонять это другой глагол. Насчет грамоты согласен, сейчас посмотрел, они не парятся. Но количество проявлений этой ошибки, которую ни в одном вопросе не исправили, как бы намекает.

Comment: @user190920  - намекает, что не парятся. Почему от склонять образуется форма с про-(или наоборот), а от склонить - не образуется. Почему от склонять не образуется форма с при- - приклонять, а от склонить образуется - приклонить?

Comment: и приклонять и приклонить - словарные слова

Comment: @user190920 Приклонять - очень редко употребленное: кто чая себе милости, и ко всем стал он приклонять слух свой. - Толстой.  Речь явно идет не о чем-то конкретном, а о преломление слышимых смыслов, внимание, стал прислушиваться к другим. Также и употребленное у Салтыкова-Щедрина "приклонял ухо" - прислушался, или еще есть приклонял Государя - просил государя, а не заставлять - разница как бы, одно заставлять - клонить, а другое изменять, просить - склонять.

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые числительные, могут менять свою форму в зависимости от рода существительного, с которым связаны, например: один процент / одна часть (доля) / одно очко / одни ножницы, два метра / две мили, полтора грамма (зернышка) / полторы тонны, оба плана (задания) / обе задачи.
При записи дробных чисел обычно используют цифры и тогда род числительного не имеет значения. Но при чтении записи (вслух), числительное приходится произносить в соответствующем (конкретному случаю) роде. Кроме того, в документах, где требуется заверить определённое количество товара, жилплощади или денежную сумму, числительные приходится записывать текстом (прописью) с учетом рода.
При текстовой записи дробных чисел нередко подразумевается связь числительного со словом ж.р. «часть» (целая часть, десятая часть, двадцать пятая...), но вместе с тем это м.б. часть: грамма, метра, гектара, градуса, часа и прочих количественных или размерных величин м.рода.
Если учесть, что при текстовой записи  дробных чисел  слова «часть», «доля» обычно упускают, поскольку их употребление считается словесным излишеством. (Слово «процент» здесь стоит особняком), то легко понять почему определение рода дробного числительного (особенно для изучающих язык) представляет трудность.
Об этом свидетельствует и подборка ответов «грамота.ру» на похожие вопросы:
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85
Выбирая вариант для ответа на вопрос Дмитрия, заметим что сочетание «два целых» недопустимо, поскольку рядом с «целая» подразумевается (пропущенное) слово «часть», а верным будет только сочетание «две целых (части)». Таким образом, из двух предложенных вариантов, правильным будет:

- Колесная база автомобиля составляет две целых и семь десятых метра.

― Итак, имеем три целых и две десятых процента. [Аркадий Львов. Двор (1981)] - пример из нац.корпуса.
Можно добавить еще один (правильный) вариант записи, в котором отсутствует слово «целая», несущая смысл «целая часть». В этом варианте записи род числительного (один / два) будет соответствовать роду измеряемой величины:

- Колесная база автомобиля составляет два и семь десятых метра.

Теперь, пока грузовик не остановится, «маяк» будет через определенные промежутки времени выплевывать миллисекундные импульсы на волне два и две десятых метра. [Андрей Лазарчук. Все, способные держать оружие... (1995)] - пример из нац.корпуса.

Answer (score 0):

При наличии **слова «целых»**  форма записи одна: *Колесная база автомобиля составляет **две целых (части) семь десятых (частей)  метра.***

Это В.п., который по форме совпадает с И.п.

**Для сравнения**: *Услуги подорожали **на девять целых три десятых процента.***

**Примечание**

Возможна  ли **упрощенная** запись? *Колесная база автомобиля **составляет два и семь десятых метра.***

Именно в этом предложении **стилистика под вопросом** (вариант на слух кажется разговорным): *Колесная **база** составляет **два***...

Сравнить: Услуги подорожали **на два и три десятых процента**. Здесь стилистка выглядит нормально.

Comment: Третий (сверху) ответ в подборке: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85 не считает такой вариант "разговорным". Не берусь подвергать сомнению позицию "грамота.ру" в этом вопросе.

Comment: Вы эту запись имеете в виду?   Как правильно: двадцать двА целых четыре десятых метра или двадцать двЕ целых четыре десятых метра? – Правильно: двадцать два и четыре десятых метра. Но лучше: 22 метра 40 сантиметров.
Попробую прокомментировать ответ. Грамота убирает слово «целых», хотя раньше этого не делала. Вероятно, это связано с тем, что число здесь составное (22). Предлагается более строгая числовая запись. Возможно, первый вариант (особенно для  составных чисел)  всё-таки разговорный. А как с простыми числами? Там «целых» везде остается,  а согласование в роде исправляется.